# How do I get $rootScope.$emit() and ng-show to work together via a D3 click event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, d3.js, angularjs-digest

I am wrapping a D3 svg image in an angular directive. When a user clicks on that D3 image I want to set a variable to true in the controller so that an ng-show then shows another D3 image.

What I have done is add a `.on("click")` function to the D3 image and in that function use `$rootScope.$emit()` to send an event. In the controller for the second image I have a `$rootScope.$on()` to ctach the event and set the variable for ng-show to true.

This approach does not work. I have tested the code to make sure that the event is emmitted and caught properly , and it is, however the ng-show does not show the second D3 image.

Why is this?

I have created a small plunkr to illustrate what I am trying to do.
http://plnkr.co/edit/FnqeAF9kVXxdUdOzT5to.

The controller code is below:

```
function CircleCtrl($rootScope) {

    this.render = function(element, attrs) {
        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", 200);

        var circle = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 30)
            .attr("cy", 30)
            .attr("r", 20);
        circle.on("click", function(d,i) {
            var data = {val0: "zero", val1: "one"};
            $rootScope.$emit("Circle Clicked", data);
        });
    };

}

function SquareCtrl($rootScope) {
    this.showSquare = false;

    $rootScope.$on("Circle Clicked", function(event, data) {
        this.showSquare = true;
    })

    this.render = function(element, attrs) {
        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", 200);

        var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 100);
    };

    }

    angular.module("AngularD3Example")
        .controller("CircleCtrl", ["$rootScope", CircleCtrl])
        .controller("SquareCtrl", ["$rootScope", SquareCtrl]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing scope of angular from outside Angular context will not update the scope variables and binding as it won't run the digest cycle of Angular.In this you are using event `click` to angular context.

You need to run `$apply()` method on a scope to `$rootScope` to run digest cycle will effectively update the binding.

**Code**

```
circle.on("click", function(d,i) {
    var data = {val0: "zero", val1: "one"};
    $rootScope.$emit("Circle Clicked", data);
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

The other thing is you need to make sure that while playing with `this` keyword you should declared it outside with some variable and then use it

**Controller**

```
function SquareCtrl($rootScope) {
    var square = this; //made this as a global can be accessible through `square` variable 
    square.showSquare = false; //<-- as changed this to square

    $rootScope.$on("Circle Clicked", function(event, data) {
        square.showSquare = true; //<-- as changed this to square
    })

    //....

}
```

You must also unregister $rootScope listeners otherwise it will cause memory leaks in your application. The return value of the .on listener is actually a function that you use when the $destroy event happens in order to achieve this

```
// Start Custom Events
var cleanApplyEvent = $rootScope.$on('submitChanges', function(event, args) {
    self.applyData(args);
})

// manually unregister rootScope listeners to avoid memory leaks
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    cleanApplyEvent();
})
// End Custom Events
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YVSZl5WS97wYjIByg6rk?p=preview)

> **Note**
>
> Its bad practice to have DOM manipulation inside controller, you
>   should create a directive an do DOM manipulation and events should be
>   handle from there

Comment: You also need to unregister $rootScope listeners otherwise it will cause memory leaks in your app.

Comment: Thank you for accepting...I made some grammatical mistakes but it's up to you to change them!

Comment: Awesome! This works for me now. @PankajParkar, I have accepted your answer. Thanks for taking the time for your thorough response.

Comment: @sail0r Glad to help you..Thanks :)